# AngularJS $scope is undefined outside of .then function

Tags: html, angularjs, select, ng-options

I have a a form which includes select input but the thing is ng-options is not working

Select code

```
<select  ng-model="selectedGender" ng-options="item.value for item in genderData">
```

I got the data from

```
 ReferenceService.searchCategory("GENDER").then(function (response){

            $scope.genderData = response.data;
            console.log($scope.genderData);

        })
```

This is the console.log($scope.genderData)

```
Array(2)
0:{referenceId: 1, category: "GENDER", key: "GENDER_KEY", value: "Male", $$hashKey: "object:3"}
1:{referenceId: 2, category: "GENDER", key: "GENDER_KEY", value: "Female", $$hashKey: "object:4"}
length:2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

but I have tried hard coding the data

```
  $scope.genderData= [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Leanne Graham",
                "username": "Bret",
                "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
                "address": {
                    "street": "Kulas Light",
                    "suite": "Apt. 556",
                    "city": "Gwenborough",
                    "zipcode": "92998-3874",
                    "geo": {
                        "lat": "-37.3159",
                        "lng": "81.1496"
                    }
                },
                "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
                "website": "hildegard.org",
                "company": {
                    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
                    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
                    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
                }
            } 
        ];
```

and it worked! but I used `ng-options="item.name for item in genderData">`

btw don't mind the data I just searched it for fast use

EDIT:

I think I found the problem. Why is it undefined outside the function?

[image]

check this console

[image]

line 244 is undefined but line 242 is not?

Comment: put your code in plunkr

Comment: https://codepen.io/mark-terrance-lim/pen/RywoKO

Comment: I don't know why it works there

Comment: check your angular plugin

Comment: @SangramBadi please check post again I edited something

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: _"Why is it undefined outside the function?"_ because the code after the `.then` runs _before_ the code inside it.

Answer (score 2):

store the response in `var` then out side the function assign that var to $scope. it is a callback issue.

If still it's showing same you can use localsorage to store and get the data. but this approach is not recomanded in angularjs. but if nothing happen then you can use this approcah also

Comment: this solved my issue but as you said I want to avoid using session storage as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

That's because `ReferenceService.searchCategory("GENDER")` returns a *promise*.

A *promise* will wait until the data is resolved, and then move on to its *success* function callback. Which is the `.then(function(response))`.

So the code will get to the `console.log` on line `244` before the promise has finished, and `$scope.genderData` has been created and therefore is `undefined`

The `console.log` on line `242` will wait until the `promise` has been resolved, and calls the success callback function.

### UPDATE:

Here an example how to correctly link the `$scope` to the `factory`.

Note that you must link to the `object` and not to its `properties` in your `$scope`.

**Wrong:**

```
$scope.gender = ReferenceService.data.genderData;
```

**Correct:**

```
$scope.gender = ReferenceService.data;
```

**Example:**

```
myApp.factory('ReferenceService',
    function ()
    {
        var ReferenceService = {
            // This is the global object. Link the $scope to this object
            data: {
                genderData: {}
            },
            searchCategory: function (type)
            {
                var getData = $http.get("URL", { params: { gender: type } }).then(
                    function (response)
                    {
                        // Store the data in the factory instead of the controller
                        // You can now link your controller to the ReferenceService.data
                        ReferenceService.data.genderData = response.data;
                    }
                )

                return getData;
            }
        }

        return ReferenceService;
    }
);

myApp.controller('MyController',
    function ($scope, ReferenceService)
    {
        // Link $scope to data factory object
        $scope.gender = ReferenceService.data;

        // Now you only have to call the factory function
        ReferenceService.searchCategory("GENDER");

        // This will now log the correct data
        console.log($scope.gender.genderData);
    }
)
```

Comment: any suggestion what to do about it?

Comment: Create the `$scope.gender` at the top of your page. So `$scope.gender = {}`;

Comment: Create a global variable inside your factory. Then link your scope to that variable.

Comment: See update, although it might be a little difficult for you to understand.